# React-Redux: Insert Data in DB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm learning to use react-redux, so sorry if I'm doing confusing!

I'm trying to create a form and insert data into the db.

Then I have created 2 page, one for the form and another one.

*RequestForm*

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let meeting = this.state.meeting;
    meeting[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ meeting });
  };

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.meeting);
    this.props.addMeeting(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <div>
          <label>Motivation:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="motivation"
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Date:</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            name="date"
            onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
          />
        </div>
```

*MeetingRequest.js*

```
import RequestForm from './RequestForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {addMeeting} from '../Redux/actions';


class MeetingRequest extends Component {

  render() {
    const addMeeting = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Request Meeting</h2>
        <RequestForm 
          addMeeting={addMeeting}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    addMeeting: (meeting) => dispatch(addMeeting(meeting)),
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MeetingRequest);
```

EDIT. Thank you to the comments the firt error is resolved, now I have a 500 problem. Could it be a problem about the Actions.js??

And also in your opinion is right how I'm trying to do??

Thank you

Comment: try `const { addMeeting } = this.props` in `MeetingRequest.js`

Comment: @MaximMazurok Now it gives me another problem about the api, but in your opionion is right how I'm operating? About action and reducers?

Comment: Because now give me a 500 error, so the problem is about the api

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: I've added answer, please, upvote/accept if it helps. Regarding 500, ask new question as it doesn't seem to be related to original question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
-const addMeeting = this.props
+const { addMeeting } = this.props
```

in `MeetingRequest.js`

---

Regarding your 500 error on API, it may be because you're sending JSON while setting `multipart/form-data`. Inspect using Network tab in dev tools.
If your backend need `multipart/form-data` you have to convert your `state.meeting` object to [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Maybe the error could be in  `addMeeting: (meeting) => dispatch(addMeeting(meeting)),` , in `mapDispatchToProps` ?? 

Anyway How can I do to convert in formdata?

Comment: @Jack23 to assist you with that I'll have to take a look at your action and reducer that actually makes request. General idea: before making request, create new FormData object and fill it with data from your meeting object, and set FormData instead of your plain meeting object.

Comment: Hi thank you for hour help. I have created a new request, if you can give me an hand, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136375/react-redux-post-action-fails-with-a-500-error